# mbean annotations @MBean missing in JDK7

Tags: annotations, jmx, java-7

I have been trying to code Mbeans using annotations only. There are a few examples I found on stackoverflow that show how to do this, however I think the @MBean is not present in JDK7. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/package-summary.html. Can someone shed some light on this.

Comment: The class is documented at least: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MXBean.html

Comment: As an aside, you might want to check out my SimpleJmx system which makes is pretty easy to do JMX with annotations: http://256.com/sources/simplejmx/

Comment: Yes, I see the docs for MXBean but are missing MBean. I was trying the examples posted http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/08/playing-with-jmx-20-annotations.html

and 

https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2007/08/defining_mbeans.html

Both the examples use MBean.

Comment: This is an old question, but I'd like to point to an annotation wrapper that I implemented. JMXWrapper is a wrapper class that allows the creation of dynamic JMX MBeans by simply annotating a normal Java class. Names and descriptions of JMX beans, attributes, operations and operation parameters can also be localized using standard Java ResourceBundles: https://github.com/uklimaschewski/JMXWrapper

Answer (score 2):

That was some forwarding looking to JMX 2.0 which never made it into Java 7, which is why you cannot find it referenced in the current docs. So I would look at something like [Gray's simplejmx](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/), or if you are using Spring, it offers some very capable JMX annotations (or you can use pure XML configuration).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have started looking at spring jmx annotations.